# NASM Windows ReadConsole NumberOfCharsRead Buffer

Tags: winapi, assembly, console, nasm, x86-64

I am attempting to convert an existing assembly program that I have so that it works on Windows. It should ask the user for their name and then output **"Hello name"**. I pretty much have it working but there is a problem with getting the number of characters actually read from the `ReadConsole` call.

My program is:

```
extern ExitProcess                          ;windows API function to exit process
extern WriteConsoleA                        ;windows API function to write to the console window (ANSI version)
extern ReadConsoleA                         ;windows API function to read from the console window (ANSI version)
extern GetStdHandle                         ;windows API to get the for the console handle for input/output

section .data                               ;the .data section is where variables and constants are defined

hello       db      'Hello '                ;db stands for 'define byte'
length      equ     $-hello                 ;get the length of the hello
                                            ;$ is the current memory location
                                            ;$-hello means the difference between the current location and
                                            ;where hello started

enter_name  db      'Please enter your name: '
name_len    equ     $-enter_name

chars       dd      0

section .bss                                ;the .bss section is where space is reserved for additional variables

name:
    resb    30                              ;reserve 30 bytes of space for the name

char_written:
    resb    4

section .text                               ;the .text section is where the program code goes

global _main                                ;tells the machine which label to start program execution from

_main:
    ;get the output handle
    mov rcx, -11                        ;specifies that the output handle is required
    call GetStdHandle                   ;returns value for handle to rax

    ;print message asking user for their name
    mov rcx, rax
    mov rdx, enter_name                 ;load the address of enter name message into rsi
    mov r8, name_len                    ;move the length into the rdx register
    mov r9, char_written

    call WriteConsoleA

    ;get the input handle
    mov rcx, -10                        ;specifies that the input handle is required
    call GetStdHandle

    ;get value from keyboard
    mov rcx, rax                        ;place the handle for operation
    mov rdx, name                       ;set name to receive input from keyboard
    mov r8, 30                          ;max number of characters to read
    mov r9, chars                       ;stores the number of characters actually read

    call ReadConsoleA

    ;print 'hello' + user's name message

    ;get the output handle
    mov rcx, -11                        ;specifies that the output handle is required
    call GetStdHandle                   ;returns value for handle to rax

    ;print message asking user for their name
    mov rcx, rax
    mov rdx, hello                      ;load the address of enter name message into rsi
    mov r8, length                      ;move the length into the rdx register
    mov r9, char_written

    call WriteConsoleA

    mov rcx, -11                        ;specifies that the output handle is required
    call GetStdHandle                   ;returns value for handle to rax

    ;print name
    mov rcx, rax
    mov rdx, name                        ;load the address of enter name message into rsi
    mov r8, chars                        ;move the length into the rdx register
    mov r9, char_written

    call WriteConsoleA


    ;exit the program

    mov rcx, 0                          ;exit code?
    call ExitProcess
```

The way that I have read the Windows API documentation on [ReadConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958(v=vs.85).aspx) is that it requires the following parameters:

- Output Handle
- Place to put the read data
- A value for the number of characters to read
- Place to put the actual number of characters read

I have defined a label `name` to receive the characters and `chars` to receive the actual number of characters.

The read call looks like this:

```
;get the input handle
mov rcx, -10                        ;specifies that the input handle is required
call GetStdHandle

;get value from keyboard
mov rcx, rax                        ;place the handle for operation
mov rdx, name                       ;set name to receive input from keyboard
mov r8, 30                          ;max number of characters to read
mov r9, chars                       ;stores the number of characters actually read

call ReadConsoleA
```

My assumption is that if the name entered is **Anna** then the value **4** or **5** (including new line character) should be stored in chars. This does not seem to be the case as when I attempt to output the name I get nothing with this code:

```
mov rcx, -11                        ;specifies that the output handle is required
call GetStdHandle                   ;returns value for handle to rax

;print name
mov rcx, rax
mov rdx, name                        ;load the address of enter name message into rsi
mov r8, chars                        ;move the length into the rdx register
mov r9, char_written

call WriteConsoleA
```

But if I switch the `chars` label out for a value it works as expected i.e.

```
mov rcx, -11                        ;specifies that the output handle is required
call GetStdHandle                   ;returns value for handle to rax

;print name
mov rcx, rax
mov rdx, name                        ;load the address of enter name message into rsi
mov r8, 4                        ;move the length into the rdx register
mov r9, char_written

call WriteConsoleA
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong with this buffer - any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: For the `WriteConsole` call you need to load the value from `chars`, not its address. Use `mov r8d, [chars]`. As usual, learn to use a debugger.